# Can i send java object in a json response

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

For example i have java class post:

```
public class Post{
String title;
String text;
}
```

If i create an instance of this class and convert it into ajax response in my servlet controller

```
@RestController
public class AjaxNewsController {
 @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @PostMapping(value = "/getPost")
    public AjaxResponseBody getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestBody AjaxPostResponse postId) {
        AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();
        result.setCode("200");
        result.setMsg("found POST");
        result.setResult(post);
        return result;

    }
}
```

My question is: can i retrieve post fields title and text with javascript on a client side and if i can then how?

Here is an example of console with my response in browse 
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5VPq.jpg)

but how can i extract my post with fields in ajax and jquery?

**UPD**

after some reaserach i found that somehow my serlvet doesn't convert my java pojo into json. How should i do it?

**UPD2**

my request sends normaly but serlvet doesn't convert POST class into json.

here is my javascript :

```
function likePost(postId,ratingElem, ratingChange) {

    var search = {}
    search["postId"] = postId;
    search["rating"] = ratingChange;

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : "likePost",
        data : JSON.stringify(search),
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            changeRating(ratingElem,data.post.getTopic());
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            changeRating(ratingElem,'error');
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
            enableSearchButton(true);
        }
    });

}
```

status and message is fine but result is empty.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. See the response of this api on browser or check via any API-testing tools like postman etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved my problem. I use com.fasterxml.jackson.core so i just need to mark fields in my class that i want to convert into json with  @JsonView annotation like

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id",
            unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private Integer postId;
```

Everything that marked will be converted.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'your_url', false); 
req.send(null);
if(req.status == 200)
dump(req.responseText);
```

and if you want to get data from another domain please read cors

Comment: i need to retrieve pojo from data in response, not to send a request.